# Django: How do I fix a RelatedOjbectDoesNotExist exception?

Tags: django

Model:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    first_nm = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=100)
    last_nm = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField('Email Address', max_length=200, unique=True )

class Invoices(models.Model):
    invoice_date = models.DateField('created date', auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users)
```

View:

```
    def post(self, request):
    bound_form = UsersForm(request.POST)

    if bound_form.is_valid() and lineItemsForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        u = Users()
        u.first_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['first_nm']
        u.last_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['last_nm']
        u.email = bound_form.cleaned_data['email']
        u.save()
        i = Invoices()
        i.user.add(u)
        i.save()
```

Right after I call i.save(), I get this:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://gpga-hrguys.rhcloud.com/players/create_user/
Django Version: 1.8.4
Exception Type: RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
Invoices has no user.
```

How can Invoices not have a user? I added it to the Invoices object just before calling i.save()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are setting the user in the Invoice wrong. Since it is a `ForeignKey`, simply put:

```
i.user = u
i.save()
```

`i.user.add(u)` would be if, user was a ManyToMany field.
And for your information, you can access all Invoices of a user by calling:

```
u.invoice_set
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
def post(self, request):
    bound_form = UsersForm(request.POST)
    if bound_form.is_valid() and lineItemsForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        u = Users()
        u.first_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['first_nm']
        u.last_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['last_nm']
        u.email = bound_form.cleaned_data['email']
        u.save()
        i = Invoices()
        i.invoice_date=datetime.now() #if you want to add current date
        i.user=u
        i.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact there you can't add ForeignKey with `add`, either you set the whole object:

```
i.user = u
i.save()
```

or you set the field that refers to ForeignKey:

```
i.user_id = u.id
i.save()
```

```py
def post(self, request):
    bound_form = UsersForm(request.POST)

    if bound_form.is_valid() and lineItemsForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        u = Users()
        u.first_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['first_nm']
        u.last_nm = bound_form.cleaned_data['last_nm']
        u.email = bound_form.cleaned_data['email']
        u.save()
        i = Invoices()
        i.user = u # modification should be here
        i.save()
```